# Why are cross-frame or -window arrays in Javascript so hard to identify?

Tags: javascript

Crockford poses a solution in *Javascript: The Good Parts* for identifying if an object is an array which goes something like this:

```
var isArray = function (obj) {
   return obj && typeof obj === "object" && obj.constructor === Array;
}
```

But then he goes on to state that

> ...it fails to identify arrays that were constructed in a different window or frame...

Why doesn't this solution work in that situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol "Array" is something that's local to each window.  Checking to see if an object constructed in a different window has a particular native constructor therefore doesn't work.

That is: in window #1, there's an "Array" constructor function. There's also one in window #2.  They're the same, of course, but they're different because they're distinct objects. When the comparison is made, it's made the way any object comparison is made: either the two values are references to exactly the same object, or they're not.

It's kind-of odd that JavaScript works this way, but it's the nature of the language.

Comment: @therin Well that's possibly one reason; you certainly wouldn't want to *share* the objects between windows.  Of course with windows in the same domain, that can be exchanging objects, that's not a huge concern, but all sorts of things would get weird if the objects (functions) were truly shared.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does a `toString.call(obj)` and if the result is `"[object Array]"`, then its `isArray()` function returns `true`.

In other cases, when jQuery may just be looking for an array-like object (including DOM collections), it just checks to see if there is a `.length` property.  That's obviously not foolproof, but it does distinguish it from a plain object or other plain type.